# CakePHP: Create a view count

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
tbl_posts
-id
-name
```

Table 2:

```
tbl_users
-id
-name
```

Now I want to count how many users have seen any post and also keep a cache count.

I would create a table for that:
(not sure if is proper name to associations)

```
tbl_posts_users 
-id
-user_id
-post_id
```

Now my questions:
What's the proper way to associate the tables? I mean, when the user visit some post, insert in tbl_posts_users (without repeated registers), and also, having two counts:
One in tbl_users, counting how many posts the user saw
One in tbl_posts, counting how many users have saw that post.

In the documentation, I didn't understand what method should I use, if I should define a belongsTo or hasMany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use meaningful table names

Based on your requirements you can name the table that logs views for example "post_views" (i.e. the viewing of a post by a user):

```
tbl_post_views
-id
-user_id
-post_id
```

If `tbl_` isn't a prefix - remove it be conventional.

Therefore there would be a model named PostView belonging to both post and user:

```
class PostView extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('Post', 'User');

}
```

### Don't use your view action to track a view

Most likely the current intention is to implement something like this:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array('Post', 'PostView');

    public function view($id) {
        $this->PostView->save(array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'post_id' => $id));
        $data = $this->Post->findById($id);
        $this->set(compact('data'));

    }
}
```

It's a better idea to *not* do that. Recording the view in the controller code has two significant-ish problems:

1. It's recording generating a view, not the user seeing it (not necessarily the same thing)
2. It interferes with caching (either in php or a user's browser)

### Use an image beacon

Instead of recording a view when the request is made, include an "image beacon" in the rendered output:

```
// end of file View/Posts/view.ctp
echo $this->Html->image(array('action' => 'viewed', $postId), array('class' => 'beacon'));
```

And in your posts controller - record that the post has been viewed, and output a valid image (otherwise there will be an error reported by the user's browser) with appropriate headers to never cache the response:

```
class PostsController extends AppController {

    ...

    public function viewed($id) {
        $this->PostView->save(array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'), 'post_id' => $id));
        $this->response->disableCache();
        $this->response->file('webroot/img/1px.gif'); // a 1px gif
        return $this->response;
    }
}
```

In this way, irrespective of how the user gets to read the content, there is a record that the user viewed the relevant page.

Comment: About saving the view/user, everything ok now, it's saving perfectly. Thanks. Just one thing, that I'm not having success: I want to save a cache in tbl_posts (or justs "posts" - I removed the prefix), 
I tried to define a counterCache => true In "belongsTo", and create a field in posts (postview_count), but the value doesn't seems to be updating. Is there anything else to do?

Comment: I fixed by passing the correct field in countercache option in PostsUser/belongsTo/Post, thanks :D